# onSelectionChanged from detaillist not firing fluentui react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I built a custom pagination and need to sustain the selection across these renders.

So if the user selects item 1 on page 1, switches to page 2, then switches back, I need to reselect item 1.

For some reason onSelectionChanged isnt firing for me, even when I select/deselect items.
This way I cant manage the selection...

```
const RelationalDataList: React.FC<IRelationalDataListProps> = (props) => {
//...
const handleSelectionChanged = () => {
        debugger;
    };

useEffect(() => {
    setSelection(() => {
        // TRY WITH NEW SELECTION ??
        if (!selectionProps) {
            return undefined;
        }
        const sel = new Selection({
            selectionMode: selectionProps.selectMultiple ? SelectionMode.multiple : SelectionMode.single,
            onSelectionChanged: handleSelectionChanged,
            canSelectItem: () => { return true; },
            items: [...list],
            getKey: (item) => {
                return item[getPrimaryKeyName(entityDefinition)];
            },
            onItemsChanged: () => { }

        });
        
        selectionProps.selectedIds.forEach((selectedId) => {
            sel.setKeySelected(selectedId, true, false);
        });

        return sel;
    });
}, []); // only one instance

  //somewhere down the line:

   
const listComponent = useMemo(() => {
    const listElement = <DetailsList
        selectionMode={selectionProps ? (selectionProps.selectMultiple ? SelectionMode.multiple : SelectionMode.single) : SelectionMode.none}
        items={list}
        columns={columns}
        selection={selection}
        selectionPreservedOnEmptyClick={true}
        getKey={(item) => { return item[pkPropName]; }}
        layoutMode={DetailsListLayoutMode.fixedColumns}
        onRenderCheckbox={(defaultProps, defaultRender) => {
            return <Stack styles={{
                root: {
                    paddingTop: '11px'
                }
            }}>{defaultRender && defaultRender(defaultProps)}</Stack>;
        }}
        styles={...}

    />;

    if (!maxHeight) {
        return <AutoSizer>
            {({ height, width }) => {
                return <Stack className='list-sizer' styles={{
                    root: {
                        height,
                        width
                    }
                }}>
                    {listElement}
                </Stack>;
            }}
        </AutoSizer>;
    }

    return listElement;
}, [selectionProps, list, columns, selection, maxHeight, pkPropName]);
```

In this case, the debugger is weirdly initiated once on load and then never again, even after selecting/deselecting items...

Comment: Can you share code for the entire component?

Comment: Gotcha. Added the section with the detaillist

Comment: This question needs clarification. You are still not showing an entire component and it is unclear what is going on. For instance, what is the `Selection()` method that is being called in the `useEffect`? What component does the `useEffect` belong to? Is all of the code above inside a single parent component? If so, when and how is it rendered? The question is incomplete as it stands

Comment: setSelection is obviously the setState react method. new Selection is obviously the constructor for the selection object that the DetailList requires. 
This is obvious...

Both the useEffect and the listComponent are inside the same component.

Comment: sorry for being so snappy... I added the component declaration on top